# PHP script failing at 'curl_exec' (attempting to extract data using REST API)

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to extract information in JSON format from a data-hosting website. After debugging using console logs, I've determined that the function stops working (times out?) at the curl_exec function (see comment).

```
function RetrieveData($account, $dataset, $kind, $apiToken)
{

$requestURI = "https://" . $account . ".example.com" . $port . "/api/dataset/" . $dataset . "/" . $kind . ".json?_at=" . $apiToken;

$session = curl_init();

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$headers = array(
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/json',
);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $requestURI);

// *****EVERYTHING RUNS FINE UP TO THIS POINT***** //

$response = curl_exec($session);
$info = curl_getinfo($session);
$responseCode = $info["http_code"];

if ($responseCode >= 300) {
print("Error loading data: " . $responseCode . "<br/>");
print($response);
} else {
$body = substr($response, $info['header_size']);
$decoded_result = json_decode($body, true);
}

curl_close($session);
return $decoded_result;

}
```

Could this be happening because the data is very large? Thanks for any help!

Comment: First thing: Have you printed out the `$requestURI` to confirm it is correct?

Comment: @Alex Yup, I have. It's accurate.

Comment: did you call the  url manually? maybe your request simply times out because the server is down. or if the data is very large, you might have to increase the maximum execution time of php.

Comment: What do you get if you put `echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($session);` after that line?

Comment: @jcfrei I've called the URL manually and the json information downloads with no problem.

Comment: @Salem If I put that just after `curl_exec($session)` I see nothing. Not even the string portion. It seems like after it times out the whole function just stops progressing.